# How to get phase and frequency of complex CSI for channel impulse responses?

Tags: python, frequency, phase, amplitude, csi

I have measurements of channel impulse responses as complex CSI's. There are two transmitters Alice and Bob and the measurements look like
`[real0], [img0], [real1], [img1], ..., [real99], [img99] (100 complex values)`.

Amplitude for the Nth value is `ampN = sqrt(realN^2 + imgN^2)`

How do I get the frequency and phase values out of the complex CSI's?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

***complex-valued Channel State Information*** ?

python has `cmath`, a standard lib for complex number math

but `numpy` and `scipy.signal` will probably ultimately be more useful to you

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab, you do `abs(csi)` to get the amplitude. To get the phase, `angle(csi)`. Search for similar functions in python